# Use a bash script/grep/sed in order to replace class names with the file name itself

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, sed

I currently have a directory that contains numerous .java files, all with different names. ie. name.java, name2.java, name3.java

I am trying to write a script that loops through all of the files in the directory and changes their class names (inside the file) to match the file name itself.

Currently, all of the .java files contain the class name MyCritter. I want to change all instances of MyCritter in each of the files to the name of the particular java file itself. I wrote a script to try and replace all of the MyCritter terms, however I am getting no change in output. The code is getting frozen after printing the echo line for the first name of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="/Users/path to folder"
subs=`ls $dir1`
for a in $subs;
do
  echo a
  [ -f "$a" ]
  grep -lr "MyCritter" * | xargs sed “s/MyCritter/$a/g”
done
```

output to terminal: name.java --> then infinite loop/gets stuck

The above code prints the name of the first file in the directory once, but then gets stuck. When I change my second line to this: `[ -f "$a" ] || continue`  it runs through the whole code, but fails to update the files.

I've tried other variations of grep including:

```
grep -lr -e "MyCritter" * | xargs sed -i “s/MyCritter/$a/g”
grep -lr -e "MyCritter" . | xargs sed -i “s/MyCritter/$a/g”
grep -lr -e "MyCritter" . | xargs sed “s/MyCritter/$a/g”
```

I was primarily using this site to guide me: http://isaacsukin.com/news/2013/06/command-line-tip-replace-word-all-files-directory

Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: The quotes around your sed command are non-standard: `”`, as opposed to `"`.

Comment: FIrst of all, always run your bash code through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/), you've got issues with what's posted.  Why are you using `xargs`?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to have a solution is *script* form, in a terminal, just `cd` to the directory containing the `*.java` files and use the following *command*:

```
for f in *.java; do sed -i "s/MyCritter/"${f%.*}"/g" "$f"; done
```

The `"${f%.*}"` portion of the `sed` *command* returns the *filename* without the *extension* and uses it to replace `MyCritter`.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, there are syntax errors in your code and [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) can easily detect those.

One of the alternate ways this can be done is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

dir1="Absolute_path_for_dir"
for f in $dir1/*.java;do
    # Extract name from /path/name.java
    filename=$(basename "$f" .java) 

    # Replace ALL occurrences of MyCritter with filename in file $f
    sed -i "s/MyCritter/$filename/g" "$f"  
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for inplace editing:

```
awk -i inplace '{gsub(/MyCritter/,FILENAME)} 1' *.java
```

or if you want to strip off the ".java":

```
awk -i inplace 'FNR==1{f=FILENAME; sub(/\.java$/,"",f)} {gsub(/MyCritter/,f)} 1' *.java
```